# Can all theories of theoretical physics be generalized to any (arbitrary) number of dimensions?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, models

Please explain from:
mathematical point of view "laws of mathematics", and, physical point of view "laws of physics"? Or is there any bound on number of dimensions?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Playing the Devil's advocate: Is the title question a meaningful question in general? If you are handed a sequence $(T(n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of theories $T(n)$ in dimension $n$, under what criteria should they be called a generalization of each other?

Comment: @Qmechanic: In the example of GR, it's pretty obvious. You write down the Einstein field equations. $G_{ab}=8\pi T_{ab}$. The field equations don't even have any reference to the number of dimensions, so there's no real question as to what is the generalization to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Notoriously, supersymmetric string theory has to be formulated in 10 dimensions in order to be consistent. Another example is supergravity, which can be formulated in a maximum of 11 dimensions otherwise it predicts particles with spins higher than two.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether there is any example of such a theory that has actually been tested by experiment and that we can be confident is right. I doubt that there is, since then theories involving large extra dimensions wouldn't have been viable.

Comment: Well general relativity has been tested, and it is mathematically consistent in any number of spatial dimensions. Actually testing it in a number of spatial dimensions other than three could be tricky :-)